# Sharing React Components across projects

Tags: reactjs

Conceptual question. I have 2 projects running on two different react services. Many components can be shared between both projects. How do I setup where I can have a "live" shared-component project, and have multiple projects using those components in real time. Through search I've read that I can do a npm package and install it that way, but wouldn't eliminate the liveness of it? Is there a way to essentially work on the components as separate projects and have multiple projects develop together.

Comment: Not tried, but see here: https://medium.com/capriza-engineering/sharing-source-code-and-libraries-in-react-bd30926df312

Comment: this seems to be what I was trying to accomplish. Having an uncompiled set where the components can grow with the projects. Will try later

Answer (score 0):

To create a shared component, we can make another repository on Git and turn it into a library. Then, you can use it as a package for your own shared-c.

Here are a few steps which you can try...

1. Add the private git repository as a dependency.
2. Specify the Branch below

   git+https://github.com/username/repository.git#branch-name
3. Open your package.json file and add the dependency like this.

   "dependencies": {
   "packageName": "git+https://github.com/username/repository.git#branch-name"
   }
4. Run npm install

it should helpful...